# Adding multiple pages with a single HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to implement a multi-page site with a single HTML document.

I want to display 'home', 'about', 'projects', and 'contact' when a user clicks on a certain link in my sidebar.

I have the following code written:

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function diff(A, B) {
            return A.filter(function (a) {
                return B.indexOf(a) == -1;
            });
        }

        function show(shown) {
            var all = ['home', 'about', 'projects', 'contact'];
            var hide_these = diff(all, shown);
            var hidden;
            document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
            for(hidden in hide_these)
                document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
            return false;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="home">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="menu-btn"></div>
                <h1>
                    Hello, World!
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('home');">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('about');">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('projects');">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('contact');">Contact</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p><br><br><br><br>Home</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="about" style="display:none">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="menu-btn"></div>
                <h1>
                    Hello, World!
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('home');">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('about');">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('projects');">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('contact');">Contact</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p><br><br><br><br>About</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="projects" style="display:none">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="menu-btn"></div>
                <h1>
                    Hello, World!
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('home');">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('about');">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('projects');">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('contact');">Contact</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p><br><br><br><br>Projects</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="contact" style="display:none">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="menu-btn"></div>
                <h1>
                    Hello, World!
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('home');">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('about');">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('projects');">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="return show('contact');">Contact</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p><br><br><br><br>Contact</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> css/main.css

```
    html,body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: arial;
    }

    html, body, #home{
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    a { 
        color: black;
    }

    a:visited { 
        text-decoration: none; 
        color: black; 
    }


    #home{
        min-height:100%;
        position:relative;
    }

    body .sidebar {
        display:block;
    }

    body.loaded .sidebar {
        display:none;
    }

    .header {
        background-color: black;
        height: 80px;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: cursive;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 2;
        color: white;
        display:flex; align-items: center; 
        z-index: 1;
        position:relative;
    }

    .menu-btn {
        background-image: url("../images/menu.png");
        height: 48px;
        width: 44px;
        margin-left:50px;
    }

    .header h1 {
        opacity: 0;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    .sidebar {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        top: 80px;
        bottom: 0;
        padding-top: 10px;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";       /* IE 8 */
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);  /* IE 5-7 */
        -moz-opacity: 0.5;          /* Netscape */
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;        /* Safari 1.x */
        opacity: 0.5;               /* Good browsers */
    }

    .sidebar li {
        color: black;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 100%;

    }

    .sidebar li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-left: 30px;
        background-color: #9da1a4;
        width: 100px; 
        padding: 8px;
        border: 1px solid silver; 
        border-radius: 5px; 
        display: block;
    }

    .sidebar li a:hover {
        background-color: #ebebeb;
    }

    .content {
        margin-top: -80px; /* Header height */
        background-image:url("../images/arbor.jpeg");
        background-size: cover;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    .content h1 {
        color: black;
    }

    .footer {
        width:100%;
        height:30px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        padding-top: 10px;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        position:absolute;
    }

    .footer a img {
        position: relative;
        top: -5px;
    }
```

but when I click on an option, it gives an expected problem: the 'page' that should be hidden isn't being hidden and only part of the requested page is being shown.

The jsfiddle found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p1u8xehL/) shows my problem.

Why isn't this working? The javascript in the head is meant to find the difference between all the pages and the page requested, show the requested page and hide the rest.

Thanks in advance,
erip

Comment: You should use a framework for creating single-page web apps for this sort of thing, rather than trying to program it manually.

Comment: I'm developing a github pages site, which doesn't permit frameworks as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/p1u8xehL/4/)

Replace

```
for (hidden in hide_these) {
            document.getElementById(hidden).style.display = 'none';
        }
```

with

```
for (hidden in hide_these) {
            document.getElementById(hide_these[hidden]).style.display = 'none';
        }
```

The problem with your code was that `document.getElementById()` was returning `null` because the values for the variable hidden was actually 0,1,2 etc.

you actually had to get the ids from the array hide_these

**UPDATE**

Add this in your CSS

The messing up of the background image is because you are missing the below given css. add them to solve the issue..

```
#about, #projects, #contact {
            width: 100%;
            height:100%;
        }
```

Comment: This works, but it messes up my background image. Any clue why?